# Dojo Gridx programattic refresh shows no data

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, dojo.gridx

I am trying to create a programmatic filter. I have a dijit.tree and a dojo gridx using the same source on a jsp. When user clicks the tree node, I want to use the node as a filter and show all rows matching it in the gridx

This is my code I have now for the onClick event of the dijit tree node.

```
                    var global=this;
                    treeWidget.onClick = function(item){

          global.grid.filter.setFilter(global.grid.filter.grid.filter.moduleClass.or("test"));
```

Earlier I asked for a sample expression. I went and tried the code above and seems to
refresh the grid but comes back as No items to display. I do have data that match test and if I do a manual filter I see data returning. What am I missing here.

At https://github.com/oria/gridx/wiki/How-to-filter-Gridx-with-any-condition%3F ( see Filter Expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish the task using the following code in the diji.tree onClick event.

```
                 global.grid.filterBar.applyFilter({
                    conditions: [{
                        condition: 'contain',
                        value: 'test'
                    }]
                });
```

Comment: thanks a lot . I searched so much for this answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment rather than an answer, but I can't post comments yet.

Can you post a working snippet of code? That's not complete, as I don't see your store that you're specifying, etc.

I usually do a myinstancename.grid.body.refresh(); to accomplish a proper refresh.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I used the following code                                global.grid.filterBar.applyFilter({
      conditions: [{
       condition: 'contain',
       value: 'test'
      }]
     });